# Ancestry Gem: Getting all categories and parent categories whose links belong to a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ancestry

Links belong_to a Collection and belongs_to a Category. A Category is an Ancestry node and can have parent and children categories.

I'm trying to retrieve all links from a collection and then group them by category, like this:

```
Category.order(:name).includes(:links).where(links: {collection_id: @collection.id})
```

The problem is that I don't have access to the empty parent categories. How would I make a where clause that would also select those categories?

Comment: By 'parent' categories, do you mean the immediate parent of matching categories, or all ancestors going up to the root?

Comment: I mean all ancestors.

Comment: So you simply want to eager load the ancestors of the matching categories, is that it?  Or did you want to do some filtering based on some ancestor attributes?  Or perhaps you wanted to return the portions of the whole tree (starting from root) that have leaves with a matching link?

Comment: Yes, I want to load the ancestors of the matching categories.